# Computer voice instanly and remotely on the phone via bluetooth?

Tags: java, mobile, bluetooth, voice, instant

Do you think it is possible to play a movie or something on the computer and hear the voice of the video instantly and remotely on a java based mobile phone via a bluetooth connection?

The speed of a bluetooth connection between the phone and the computer is like 40 KB/s and that looks enough for a voice transmission. But i couldn't find any software that can do this. Please someone give me info about the the possibility of my wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it if the Bluetooth device supports Handsfree profile or A2DP sink profile

typically a mobile phone would not support these profile roles (they would support the opposite role Audio Gateway / A2DP source) So you will not be able to route the voice to the mobile phone.
But a Bluetooth headset that support these roles (most do) will be able to get the audio routed to it.
Does it help ?